# Issues using a XBox 360 GamePad to play Call of Duty: Black Ops on a PC

Tags: pc, call-of-duty-black-ops, controllers

I'm playing Call of Duty: Black Ops on my PC with an XBox 360 GamePad and it's working pretty well.  Unfortunately there are two very annoying issues.

The most annyoing thing is that I've got a problem with the switch for ADS.  When I press the LT to aim down the sights sometimes it instantly switches back, but the button is pressed. I guess it may be a result of pressing on the left stick for sprint, but I'm not quite sure.  Is it me,  the controller, the game or something else?  Does anyone else have this problem - maybe on the XBox too?

The second issue is that I'm not able to navigate through the menu using the pad. I always need to switch back to M/K to choose a class or join a server. Is there no support for this or do I need to edit some configuration file to get this working?

Comment: So let me get this straight, you're playing on the PC and you chose to use a GamePad?  WHYYYYYYYY?????!!  There's a good chance that they just screwed up on the GamePad controls since they're kinda expecting a PC user to use PC peripherals.  That's not an uncommon thing.

Comment: I played FPS on PC for over 15 years now and I just like the difference a gamepad made. The controls are so nice, it's just a different experience in gaming. Besides that many PC-Games are just consoleports and work pretty good (or better!) then with M/K. It's kinda sad, that I need to explain WHY i chose the gamepad, instead of someone just answering my Question. Be a bit more open-minded dude ;)

Comment: I'd offer an answer if I had one.  I don't unfortunately so all I can do is comment.  Don't take it as an attack on you, just long time PC gamer to long time PC gamer, I was shocked (and was a bit of non-serious gesture I might add).

Comment: I don't take it as an attack. It's just a common reaction on every site some asks about controllersupport. I never thought of playing FPS with a pad, but then i bought a PS3 and started to play some Battlefield. After many different FPS i decided to buy a Xbox-pad for my PC, because it's the most supported controller. So much fun, such a different experience. It's pretty awesome, if you're not that kind of guy that just watches on K/D-R ;)

Answer (score 1):

I use a controller for all of my PC games as well. I can't stand using the M/K. Never have and never will. I play the game for fun. I've been hesitant to even try online MP because I'm afraid I'll get my butt kicked too bad and won't enjoy it.

I don't have any issues with ADS with my controller. Perhaps the left trigger on your pad is starting to go bad? Have you tried calibrating the controller in the Windows control panel? Perhaps that'll help.

The controller is only set up to work in-game and not the menus. It was programmed that way and I don't think it can be changed.

Comment: Sorry for that late reply. The problem only occurs in CoD BO, so I don't think my pad is going bad. I thought the gamemechanic itself is a bit broken on the PC or something else.